# java web server - newly created file not found by browser, until server restart

Tags: java, tomcat7, http-status-code-404, file-not-found

I have a tomcat 7.0 web server on my local machine, when doing a GET call to server i create a file (image), save it on server and give the browser the URL to fetch.

The browser gets a 404 "file not found" for the URL, even after I refresh the browser same 404.
Only after I restart the server the browser finds the file and all goes as planned.

I have tried giving it read permissions, but it did not help.

Where to look for the problem?

Tomcat Version : Apache Tomcat/7.0.12,
Servlet Specification Version : 3.0.

the file is saved under /projectName/WebContent/resources/images.

URL for accessing file: "http://localhost:8080/projectName/resources/images/2.png."

before a response to the GET call is returned the file already exists (also the file is not found after browser refresh - meaning another call).

as for cache settings, I have none, here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>ProjectName</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/configuration/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>        
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/configuration/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I believe that tomcat creates a file cache when you start it and copies everything there. I don't know if there's a way to force a cache update other than restarting the server. Maybe locate the cache folder and put your new files there as well.

Comment: @Tal Exact Tomcat version? Location you are creating the file? URL you are using to access the file? Do you attempt to access the file before it exists? Cache settings for your Context? Anti-JAR locking settings (if any)?

Comment: Hello @MarkThomas, i have added the details in the question

Comment: @MarkThomas what details are missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is part of your application path, I presume identified in a context.xml, then it will not be visible until the context is redeployed. When a context is deployed, it is copied to work and run from there. Only WEB-INF/web.xml is watched for changes, changes to other files should not have any effect (except for JSP if you are running in dev mode).

1. You can store files outside any webapp folder path, this is a best practice
2. Write a servlet to fetch them from that directory for example /getpic/filename.png would look in c:\images\filename.png for the file, and stream it back to the user.

Comment: but i wont always have access to path outside my webapp, i can not save and serve files from outside my webapp.

am now considering base64 encoding of the image

Comment: you already do. Your server writes logs to %TOMCAT_BASE/logs, for instance. Your application directory (%TOMCAT_BASE/webapps) is expected to remain static, unless you are deploying. I do not see how base64 encoding is of any help to you.

Comment: i couldn't find the image file any where else but inside my webapp (where i originally created it), actually i couldn't find any of the static files outside my webapp folder or in the server (tomcat) folder, looking at %TOMCAT_BASE/webapps i do not see my project name as a folder (do i need to define something to do that).

As for base64, it will save me creating the file at all, and i am still able to present the image in the browser (i know it is not a solution but a workaround, and a solution is always better)